# In what format does Oracle expect a date value, and how can I give Oracle what it wants?

Tags: c#, winforms, oracle, datetime, dotconnect

"AVAILABLEDATE" is a column of type DATE.

I can query the table via Toad and get results. However, in (Winforms/C#/dotConnect) code, it's not working.

```
ocmd.Parameters.Add("AVAIL_DATE", getDateToQuery());
```

I'm pretty sure the problem is the way I'm passing the date:

```
private DateTime getDateToQuery() {
  DateTime candidateVal = dateTimePickerScheduleDate.Value;
  if (candidateVal.Equals(null)) {
    candidateVal = DateTime.Now;
  }
  return candidateVal;
}
```

...but I don't know how to force the date value to be in the format Oracle will recognize.

Comment: What is the select statement you have put into the command?  The parameter markers are different for .NET and Toad.

Comment: what error message are you getting?

Comment: No err msg, just wasn't returning any vals; fixed now - see below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works, but I'm not sure it's the best way:

```
int iFromYear = dateTimePickerScheduleDate.Value.Year;
int iFromMonth = dateTimePickerScheduleDate.Value.Month;
int iFromDay = dateTimePickerScheduleDate.Value.Day;
. . .
ocmd.Parameters.Add("AVAIL_DATE", new DateTime(iFromYear, iFromMonth, iFromDay));
```

Answer (score 4):

Try adding the parameter type:

```
OracleParameter p1 = new OracleParameter("AVAIL_DATE", OracleDbType.Date);
p1.Value = getDateToQuery();
ocmd.Parameters.Add(p1);
```

Also, make sure you provide the parameters **in order**, the last time I worked with Oracle I remember the names of the parameters were ignored.

Comment: Seems elegant, but it doesnt' work - my kludgy way works, though...?

Comment: @ClayShannon other than the type I don't see what the difference is, did you change anything else? perhaps your function getDateToQuery() was not returning the value you needed?